# meaning of "secured"

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Sviridov’s 2nd Guards Mechanized Corps, advanced south of Budapest from small bridgeheads over the Danube River, which the Soviets had seized in late November. From there, this second force **secured** Székesfehérvár and Esztergom, west of Budapest.
> (book:  When Titans Clashed)

What does "secured" mean, captured? I cannot bring it into alignment with dictionaries.

Comment: Please limit your questions to just asking one single question. Although "there" and "secured" appear close to each other in the same passage, the questions are not at all related. Please edit this to be about the one you want the answer to. If you want to know both, please ask the other in a new question. Also, you should show what thinking you've already done and what you're still unsure about

Comment: Yes, it means that they captured those towns. (_Secure_ can mean _get into your possession_.)

Comment: "secured" is a common military term.  As noted by @gotube 's answer, it means "gain long lasting control".  In the paragraph given, "secured" implies that resistance has ceased.

Answer (score 2):

Here, "secure" means "gain long-lasting control", which in the context implies capturing first.

> [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/secure):
> **3 a :** to get secure usually lasting possession or control of